# Optimal storing structure for an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm developing a website in EC2 and I have a lampp server in the original `/opt/lampp` folder. The thing is that I store all my images related to the website including users' profile images there(`/opt/lampp/htdocs`). I doubt this is the most efficient way? I have links to the images in my MySQL server.

I actually have no idea of what Amazon EBS and Amazon S3 is, how can I utulize it?

Answer (score 3):

EBS is like an external usb hard drive. You can easily access content from filesystem (/mnt/).

S3 is more like an API based cloud storage. You'll have much more work to integrate it into your system.

You have a pretty good summary here :
http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-amazon-s3-and-amazon-ebs/

Google has a lot of infos about this.